# Missing GLIBC executing the ring interpreter after recent update

Tags: ubuntu, glibc, ring

When executing the ring interpreter after a recent update to 1.13 on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS I get the following error:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/libring.so)
I've tried a re-install with no success. Anyone have a work-around?
Dick S.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This kind of question should be asked in ServerFault rather than here.  That said, my understanding of this kind of error is that libm requires 2.29 of glibc which isn't present.  I'm not familiar with ring interpreter, so not sure how that applies here.  Use a version of libm that is compatible with your current glibc?  (that's my guess)

Comment: You should also explain exactly what you did to reinstall.

Comment: I followed the README.TXT that comes with the zip file, except for one thing -- the install.sh wants to create a /usr/lib64 directory and put a bunch of files in there and there already was a binary by that name so I moved it  to a SAVE directory, created a /usr/lib64 directory and re-ran install.sh

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04LTS and ring seems to work fine after re-install. I found a post elsewhere that noted that Ubuntu 20.x includes glibc 2.29 which is required for the ring release. Seems like the ring developers ought to mention this. Thanks for everyone who read my question and suggested remedies.